# regex writes on "empty variable" & "not empty variable"

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm quite exploring regex. All my regex are working using a trial and error. I'm very confused of writting for the empty variables.

i have this regex:

```
<[^>]*id=\"test3\"(.*)value=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>

<input name="token" type="text" id="test3" value="valueA">
```

which search **id="test3"** and writes a on a **value="valueA"**. yes it 'works' but my problem is it won't if the **value=""** is empty. I'm very very confused on matching tags.

like if I execute the regex above in with this tag

```
<input name="token" type="text" id="test3" value="">
```

EX:

PHP:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

$data['test1'] = 'TOKEN 1';

$data['test2'] = 'TOKEN 2';

foreach ($data as $id => $value)
{

    if(preg_match('%<[^>]*id=\"'.$id.'\"(.*)value=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>%', $html, $match))
    {
        $html = str_replace($match[2], $value, $html);
    }

}

echo $html;

?>
```

HTML:

```
<input name="token1" type="text" id="test1" value="" />

<input name="token2" type="text" id="test2" value="B" />

</body>
</html>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

`TOKEN 1`

`TOKEN 2`

it won't write any variable in the empty **value=""** kindly help me with matching?

I have include a link for a test to my regex

[TRY IT!](http://regex101.com/r/pZ5yC3/#debugger)

there's a good answer from this question but I'm really confused on matching

[MATCHED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017016/writes-value-in-a-empty-tag-on-php)

Comment: I just checked on your link and it's capturing the empty string with index range from 50 to 50.

Comment: yup example: `$match[2]` captures the empty string but it won't write anything.

Comment: Since the string is empty, what could be written out?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Basically, what you should do is capture everything starting from value=" " in your group and then append it to the value to be inserted as well. See my answer below.

Comment: Please see the updated answer as well. It now has a link to the regex site you are using. preg_replace looks like a better solution.

Comment: yup I seen it kindly check my updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*\bid=\"test3\"[^>]*\bvalue=\"\K[^\"]*/', $value, $html);
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/nA6S9k)**.

---

**UPDATE** *(based on OP's comment)*

```
if (preg_match('/(<[^>]*\bid=\"test3\"[^>]*\bvalue=\")([^\"]*)/', $html, $match))
{
  $html = str_replace($match[1].$match[2], $match[1].$value, $html);    
}
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/SZeR5q)**.

Comment: @Darline - I have updated my answer with alternative solution that may work for you...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform a replacement with a regex, you must use the `preg_replace()` function:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<[^>]*?\bid="test3".*?\svalue="\K[^"]*(?="[^>]*>)/is',
                     'A', $html);
```

pattern details:

```
<[^>]*?\bid="test3" 
.*?                #  I use a lazy quantifier to avoid to match
                   # the last "value" attribute of the file
\svalue="          #  The space prevent you to match an
                   # hypotetic "abcdvalue" attribute
\K                 #  remove all that have been matched before from 
                   # the match result
[^"]*              #  all characters that are not a "
(?="[^>]*>)        #  a lookahead to check the end of the tag.
                   # it's only a check, the subpattern inside 
                   # is not in the match result too
```

The `s` modifier at the end is for dotall mode ( the `.` can match newlines too )

To use it with your array you can simply do this:

```
foreach ($data as $id=>$value) {
    $html = preg_replace('/<[^>]*?\bid="' . $id . '".*?\svalue="\K[^"]*(?="[^>]*>)/is',
                         $value, $html);
}
```

Comment: i need some preg_match operator :(

Comment: @Darline: What's strange! But Why?

Comment: @Darline: wait a minute, it's not a problem.

Comment: @casirmir ok take your time :)

Comment: thank you I will make this a reference but I go to  Ωmega answer. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
<[^>]*id=\"test3\"(.*)(value=\".*?\")[^>]*>
```

Then in your code, do this:

```
$html = str_replace($match[2], 'value="'.$value.'"', $html);
```

Check it on regex101.com: http://regex101.com/r/qF9yH4

Comment: it won't work what if the some `value` is not empty?

Comment: Then it'll capture both the fixed part - 'value="' and the actual value itself.

Comment: nope it doesn't work. if there's 2 empty variable it don't work